# How to find an array that only contains unique items among multiple arrays?

Tags: algorithm

Example:

input:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4]
array2 = [1,2]
array3 = [3]
array4 = [5,6]
```

output:

```
array4
```

input:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4]
array2 = [1,2]
array3 = [3,5]
array4 = [5,6]
```

output:

```
None
```

How to design a solution in an efficient way(less time complexity)?

Comment: which programming lanugage ?

Comment: *"get array4 from the 4 arrays"*: what do you mean with "get array4"? You already have it.

Comment: You can just describe the algorithm or use python, I am trying to find an algorithm with less time complexity. What I mean 'get array4' here is to find the array that only contains unique items compared with all the arrays, not just output array4, actually we don't know which array is the right one, the objective is to find one with the appropriate algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one potential approach.

```
Time complexity: O(num_arrays * max_length_among_num_arrays)
Space complexity: O(sum_of_length_of_num_arrays)
```

```js
const array1 = [1,2,3,4]
const array2 = [1,2]
const array3 = [3]
const array4 = [5,6]
const arrays = [array1, array2, array3, array4];

// Generate a mapping of: value -> number of arrays that have it
const map = new Map();
for (const arr of arrays) {
    const set = new Set(arr);
    for (const item of set) {
        if (!map.has(item)) {
            map.set(item, 0);
        }
        map.set(item, map.get(item) + 1);
    }
}

// Find arrays for which all items have only appeared in one array
const res = [];
for (const arr of arrays) {
    let check = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length && check; i++) {
        if (map.get(arr[i]) > 1) {
            check = false;
        }
    }
    if (check) {
        res.push(arr);
    }
}

console.log(res);
```